# Extract Arabic characters from string

Tags: php, laravel, string

This is a string sample: "521ن11 66"

I want to extract the "ن" from the string.

I used `substr()`, the result is a symbol: `�`

I used `str_split()`, the result is

```
array:10 [▼
  0 => "5"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "1"
  3 => b"Ù"
  4 => b"†"
  5 => "1"
  6 => "1"
  7 => " "
  8 => "6"
  9 => "6"
]
```

The length of the string is always the same but the numbers and character change.

Please provide code samples.

Cheers.

Comment: Try the `mb_*` multibyte equivalent string functions, ie `mb_str_split()` or `mb_substr()`. Note some of them are only available on certain PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with the help of @cOle2

This piece of code did the trick:

```
preg_split('//u', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

This splits the characters as `str_split()` and return the actual value of the character.

Comment: just remember it's a multibyte character, and also remember that combining marks are _separate_ characters in this case.

Answer (score -1):

You might have to convert it to unicode somehow, or look up it's unicode value and then convert back when needing to print it. You might be able to try a library that is capable of dealing with the Arabic alphabet